# tfoot breaks anchor links after printing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

## Why do anchor links to content inside the tbody of a table stop working correctly after printing a page using the Chrome browser and utilizing tfoot?

*here is a markup example that will demonstrate the problem*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      body {
        max-width: 996px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .footer {
        background-color: tomato;
      }

      .content-table {
        height: calc(100vh * 3);
      }

      .txt {
        margin-top: 100vh;
      }

      .txt:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: rgb(195, 252, 233);
      }

      .txt:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: rgb(180, 146, 213);
      }

      .txt:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: rgb(109, 109, 197);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PDF generation</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td><a href="#txt_1">To txt 1</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td><a href="#txt_2">To txt 2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td><a href="#txt_3">To txt 3</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="content-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td>
            <p id="txt_1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt fugiat et magni
              praesentium expedita ratione illum numquam sapiente sequi laborum consectetur dolorem
              ad mollitia, tempore eos nam cum molestiae nulla!
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td>
            <p id="txt_2">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt fugiat et magni
              praesentium expedita ratione illum numquam sapiente sequi laborum consectetur dolorem
              ad mollitia, tempore eos nam cum molestiae nulla!
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txt">
          <td>
            <p id="txt_3">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt fugiat et magni
              praesentium expedita ratione illum numquam sapiente sequi laborum consectetur dolorem
              ad mollitia, tempore eos nam cum molestiae nulla!
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot class="footer">
        <tr>
          <td><p>This is footer</p></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

As can be seen after printing, each subsequent link opens with an error in the cumulative height of all preceding tfoot.